# Runtime Exception while running composer update on Symfony2 on localhost

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm getting a runtime exception while updating my dependencies with composer. Here's the trace:

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:158
 Composer\Downloader\GitDownloader->cleanChanges() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/VcsDownloader.php:89
 Composer\Downloader\VcsDownloader->update() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:255
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->update() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:176
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->updateCode() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:105
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->update() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:173
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->update() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:140
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:529
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:215
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:123
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:892
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/bin/composer.phar:15
```

I haven't got a clue what's going on with that! And now I can't even add a vendor bundle to my application :(

I got this right after I respond n when it ask me if I want to discard changes on the modified files..

```
Updating sensio/distribution-bundle (v2.2.6 => 2.2.x-dev 2779c8b)
    The package has modified files:
--- somes files...
```

Comment: What's the exception message and file/linenumber? You have only included the trace. btw if you want to discard the changes anyways you can easily delete the `sensio/distribution-bundle` folder located in `vendor` before updating again. This looks like a permission issue on invocation of `cleanChanges()`.

Comment: There's no linenumber because I run it in the terminal. I'm pretty sure you're write with the permission thing. I've red that it happens a lot when you develop on symfony with a mac. I ran it at school on a pc and everything went fine... until I found out that I forgot the symfony files on the local server there haha. I'll have to investigate more with permission on osx. Thanks for pointing me that out.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error very often.. here is an example for a different bundle:

[image]

You can type `$git diff` to see what changes composer is talking about.

If you haven't made any changes into `sensio/distribution-bundle`, just type **y** and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. (Composer will ask "Would you like to discard the changes?)

It's because composer can see that there have been some modifications in `sensio/distribution-bundle`.

**There are 2 cases for this:**

<kbd>1</kbd> You really did make some changes into the vendor files, in this case `sensio/distribution-bundle`. And you should never do this... If you want to do this, just fork in this case `sensio/distribution-bundle` and add it to your `composer.json` file:

```
"repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:YourUsername/SensioDistributionBundle.git"
      },
    ],
"require": {
        //...
        "sensio/distribution-bundle":"dev-master",
        //...
      },
//...
```

<kbd>2</kbd> You haven't made any changes.

you have made some changes into the vendor files, in this case `sensio/distribution-bundle`. In can also happen depending on the IDE or OS you are using. In this case, always reply YES. If these files are created by your IDE or OS, simply add them to your `.gitignore` file:

```
# PHP Storm generated files #
.idea
# OS generated files #
*.DS_Store
```